# SQL Select from multiple tables while matching values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use the SQL statement below, to retrieve data from 3 tables. I get a syntax error near [aren1002] however.

```
select
holiday_notes.*,
HOLIDAY_REF.holiday_name as holiday_name from [aren1002].[HOLIDAY_NOTES]
left join [aren1002].[HOLIDAY_REF] on holiday_notes.holiday_id=HOLIDAY_REF.holiday_id

[aren1002].[lookup].lookup_desc as type_desc from [aren1002].[HOLIDAY_NOTES]
left join [aren1002].[lookup] on holiday_notes.[type]=lookup.lookup_id

where [HOLIDAY_NOTES].delete_date is null order by [HOLIDAY_NOTES].create_date desc
```

I'm trying to add the holiday_name column from HOLIDAY_REF and type_desc from the second table (lookup). I'm not totally sure how to structure the statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The columns you are selecting need to be put right after the `SELECT` portion of your query, then you put the `FROM` clause next, along with any join criteria. After that, you can put your `WHERE` clause.

```
select
holiday_notes.*,
HOLIDAY_REF.holiday_name as holiday_name,
[aren1002].[lookup].lookup_desc,
[aren1002].[lookup].type_desc

from [aren1002].[HOLIDAY_NOTES]
left join [aren1002].[HOLIDAY_REF] on holiday_notes.holiday_id=HOLIDAY_REF.holiday_id
left join [aren1002].[lookup] on holiday_notes.[type]=lookup.lookup_id
where [HOLIDAY_NOTES].delete_date is null order by [HOLIDAY_NOTES].create_date desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `FROM` in there.

Try this

```
select
holiday_notes.*,
HOLIDAY_REF.holiday_name as holiday_name,
[aren1002].[lookup].lookup_desc as type_desc
 from [aren1002].[HOLIDAY_NOTES]
left join [aren1002].[HOLIDAY_REF] on holiday_notes.holiday_id=HOLIDAY_REF.holiday_id
left join [aren1002].[lookup] on holiday_notes.[type]=lookup.lookup_id
where [HOLIDAY_NOTES].delete_date is null order by [HOLIDAY_NOTES].create_date desc
```

A select statement will normally follow the pattern of:
`SELECT` *required fields* `FROM` *table* (optionally) `JOIN` *join statements to other tables* `WHERE` *conditions*

Answer (score 0):

I'm no sql guru, and I'm not at a system where I can set up a test quickly, so this may be completely and totally wrong.

But I'm pretty sure you should do all your SELECTs first, then specify the FROM and JOINs.

So I think you want something along the lines of:

select
holiday_notes.*, HOLIDAY_REF.holiday_name as holiday_name, [aren1002].[lookup].lookup_desc as type_desc
from [aren1002].[HOLIDAY_NOTES]
left join [aren1002].[HOLIDAY_REF] on holiday_notes.holiday=HOLIDAY_REF.holiday_id
left join [aren1002].[lookup] on holiday_notes.[type]=lookup.lookup_id
where [HOLIDAY_NOTES].delete_date is null
order by [HOLIDAY_NOTES].create_date desc